# Dictionary comprehension: change the last item in a list value

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a Python dictionary mapping strings to lists of strings.

- I want to change the last item of each list to uppercase using a dictionary comprehension

E.g. for this example

```
dd = {'cc': ['aa', 'UU', 'zzzzzzz'], 't': ['aa', 'uu', 'ZZZZZZ']}
```

I want this:

```
{'cc': ['aa', 'UU', 'ZZZZZZZ'], 't': ['aa', 'uu', 'ZZZZZZ']} # note the last item in the first list
```

I thought I could just re-assign the last item via indexing and tried variations of this

```
{k: (v[-1] = v[-1].upper()) for k,v in dd.viewitems()} 
# --> returns syntax error
# or this, which returns None:
{k: v[:-1].append(v[-1].upper()) for k,v in dd.viewitems()}
#the below works but I don't like it
{k: [i if not v.index(i) == len(v)-1 else i.upper() for i in v] for k,v in dd.viewitems()}
```

I can't get it to work w/out a dirty list comprehension.

- Is there a good way to do this?

(I am on Py 2 though through no fault of my own)

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't really something you should do in a dict comprehension. A normal loop would be far more readable.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You could, technically, re-create the dict values and update their last item within a dict comprehension but chances are that It will be slower than just straight loop/update, not to mention the readability.

Comment: You can't assign in a dict comprehension, because assignment is not an expression. If you want to use assignment, use a normal loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use unpacking:

```
dd = {'cc': ['aa', 'UU', 'zzzzzzz'], 't': ['aa', 'uu', 'ZZZZZZ']}
new_d = {a:[c, d, e.upper()] for a, [c, d, e] in dd.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'cc': ['aa', 'UU', 'ZZZZZZZ'], 't': ['aa', 'uu', 'ZZZZZZ']}
```

However, for lists with arbitrary numbers of elements, you can use negative indexing:

```
new_d = {a:b[:-1]+[b[-1].upper()] for a, b in dd.items()}
```

Comment: wow this is wild/cool and does exactly what I want (but I see the other commenters' concerns re readability). thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use a simple `for` loop:

```
dd = {'cc': ['aa', 'UU', 'zzzzzzz'], 't': ['aa', 'uu', 'ZZZZZZ']}

for v in dd.itervalues():
    v[-1] = v[-1].upper()

print dd

{'cc': ['aa', 'UU', 'ZZZZZZZ'],
 't': ['aa', 'uu', 'ZZZZZZ']}
```

A dictionary comprehension cannot contain assignments, and so is inappropriate for the logic you are attempting to apply.

Comment: point taken. I was mainly looking for a dict comprehension/oneliner since this is part of a class attribute, but I see what you mean. Thank you